# Run apex class after deploy

Tags: apex, callout

Objective: After deployment is completed, use [deployCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_Metadata_DeployCallback.htm) to make a request to a rest API

I wrote the following code and put it in my SF instance

```
public class DeployStatus implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result,
                             Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            // Deployment was successful
            PostPipeline PostPipelineData = new PostPipeline();
            PostPipelineData.setDeployStatus('succeeded', result.Id);
            
        } else {
            // Deployment was not successful
            PostPipeline PostPipelineData = new PostPipeline();
            PostPipelineData.setDeployStatus('failed', result.Id);            
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. After a deployment in SF, regardless if it was successful or not, I did not receive any requests in my rest API also, I don't see any error message related to my apex class.

Could someone help and tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am not an SF developer, I work with DevOps and I am just trying to solve a issue re to deploy package.xml

Answer (score 3):

`Metadata.DeployCallback` is used with the [Apex Metadata API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api). It has no effect if you perform a deployment from outside the Salesforce platform using a `package.xml` manifest.

There is no way to effect a callback upon a Metadata API deployment completing, in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to run custom code when the deployment completes, like an event or trigger?

Comment: @JoaoVitorino if deploying with sfdx, just write a shell script for it.

Comment: Even if not using SFDX, any Metadata API tool should be able to poll for completion so that your automation "knows" when it's done.

Comment: That is the problem, I don´t want to check from time to time if the deploy finished, this is costing a lot of minutes of CICD. Using sfdx in a while loop is what I am doing right, instead, I created a listener that waits for a request when the deployment finishes. Right now I need to find a way, an event or trigger, to fire an apex code that will do the API request.

Comment: You really cannot do that. You have to poll, one way or another.